# Is this a basis of $L^p([0,1])$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Do the set of functions: $\{1 , \frac{1}{x+1}, \frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)}, \dots \}$ form a (non-orthonormal) Schauder basis of $L^p([0,1])$ for $1 \le p < \infty$? How can I prove or disprove this statement?

Comment: What kind of basis do you mean? Do you mean a Hamel basis?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven edited

Comment: I can think of some reasons this seems unlikely; what are your thoughts?

Comment: Just consider the characteristic function of $[0.5, 1]$ and show that you cannot approximate it with elements of your basis.